# Python get all paths from graph

Tags: python, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I'm trying to find the paths that a user could take through a website. I have represented my graph using this format:

```
graph = { 0 : [1, 2],
          1 : [3, 6, 0],
          2 : [4, 5, 0],
          3 : [1],
          4 : [6, 2],
          5 : [6, 2],
          6 : [1, 4, 5]}
```

I have implemented a depth first algorithm, but it needs a change for it to be useful. It needs to return the path and not just the nodes in the order it goes to them.

```
visitedList = [[]]
def depthFirst(graph, currentVertex, visited):
    visited.append(currentVertex)
    for vertex in graph[currentVertex]:
        if vertex not in visited:
            depthFirst(graph, vertex, visited)
    return visited

traversal = depthFirst(graph, 0, visitedList)
print('Nodes visited in this order:')
print(visitedList)
```

That function returns this:

```
[[], 0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 5]
```

Whereas I want something like this:

```
[[0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 6], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When passing a list in python it does not deep copy. Using list.copy() can really help here. I'm not sure this is what you wanted but here is the code:

```
visitedList = [[]]

def depthFirst(graph, currentVertex, visited):
    visited.append(currentVertex)
    for vertex in graph[currentVertex]:
        if vertex not in visited:
            depthFirst(graph, vertex, visited.copy())
    visitedList.append(visited)

depthFirst(graph, 0, [])

print(visitedList)
```

It returns all the paths.

```
[[], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 5], [0, 1, 6, 4, 2], [0, 1, 6, 4], [0, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4], [0, 1, 6, 5, 2], [0, 1, 6, 5], [0, 1, 6], [0, 1], [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3], [0, 2, 4, 6, 1], [0, 2, 4, 6, 5], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4], [0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 3], [0, 2, 5, 6, 1], [0, 2, 5, 6, 4], [0, 2, 5, 6], [0, 2, 5], [0, 2], [0]]
```

List copy worked for me in python3.

Comment: Worked a treat. If anyone is wondering why it may crash their IDE, it may be because you are linking them up to the previous node. I slightly altered my version of this to exclude the previous node's connection and it worked without any issues